Smart Keyboard like Unicode character with built-in functionality such as iPhone shortcut?
To reduce screen footprint, I need to shorten date and timestamp. Example is January or shortest as Jan is more ambiguous compared to single character ㋀ for Chinese literates. I prefer built-in functionality over APP  to minimise maintenance such as downloading them after resetting device to improve performance.i tried JSON.
Is there iPhone shortcut Action to generate Unicode character?
Example
CHAR(12992)to output ㋀

Some context might help here: Do you need a shortcut to generate a specific, pre-defined Unicode character, or any? From where would you trigger it, where should the result be inserted into? What have you tried so far?
